# Strange behavior of mcexam package

Tags: overleaf, mcexam

I am using the mcexam package to writ exam papers on Overleaf.

The package only works well when I specify permutation option after `\begin{mcanswerslist}`.

[image]

An MWE is shown below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[output=exam,
            numberofversions=1,
            version=1,
            seed=4,
            writeRfile=false,
            randomizequestions=true,
            randomizeanswers=true]{mcexam}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}


\title{Testing mcexam package}
\author{An author}
\date{October 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Test}
\begin{mcquestions}

\question How much is $2+2$?
\begin{mcanswerslist}[fixlast]
\answer two
\answer[correct] four
\answer five
\end{mcanswerslist}

\question How much is $5-3$?
\begin{mcanswerslist}[fixlast]
\answer 1
\answer[correct] 2
\answer 3
\end{mcanswerslist}

\question How much is $0 \times 2$?
\begin{mcanswerslist}[fixlast]
\answer 1
\answer 2
\answer[correct] none of the above
\end{mcanswerslist}

\end{mcquestions}


\end{document}
```

Whenever I remove the permutation options, like `[fixlast]` option, it cannot generate the pdf file. For example, if I remove the option `[fixlast]` from question `\question How much is $2+2$?`, the error is shown in the blow picture.

In the documentation of the mcexam package, I see a lot of examples that don't have this option since it specifies that

> permuteall: With this option, all answers are permuted in the different
> versions of the exam. This is the default option and doesn’t need to be
> given explicitly.

Is there any fix that allows us to write answers without specify permutation option? Since I really don't want to write this option every time I start a new question.

[image]

Comment: The bug appears to be fixed in the latest version of `mcexam` (I just tested it with your MWE), see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mcexam. For Overleaf you should be able to download the `mcexam.sty` file from CTAN, upload it to your Overleaf project, and then it is used automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much, using the last `mcexam.sty` works well in my tex file. It looks like Overleaf has not included the latest `mcexam` version in its TeX distribution.  Please make your solution as a separate answer and I will mark as it as the answer for my question.

Comment: Usually we close questions that are caused by using old versions, because they are 'not reproducible' (once you have the new version).